# Residual estimation for negative binomial regression in Stata

Tags: stata

I am new to generalised linear modelling. I ran the negative binomial model, and then try to estimate the residuals from the model.

Here is what I did:

1. Run a negative binomial regression model with `nbreg` command in stata 17.
2. Run the `predict` command to estimate the predicted values.
3. Then, `generate` the residual by subtracting predicted values from observed values.

Did I do it correctly?

Comment: Hi Simon, welcome to StackOverflow! If your question is about what is valid in statistics you are more likely to get a useful answer here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/ StackOverflow is for help with programming. If you edit your question, show in code what you have done and explain what error related to programming you are facing.

Comment: I agree with @TheIceBear. This is essentially a statistical question with code examples. But a Stata-based comment is that there are many flavours of residuals and in this case the plain difference observed MINUS predicted isn't necessarily even the best one to use. If you switch to `glm` you'll find other flavours readily available after estimation. In just about any other language, general and specialised routines may differ in what is immediately and easily provided or available.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind advice! I'll check on stats.stackexchange.com  as @TheIceBear suggested.